Finding shortest line between feature tool with barrier layer in QGIS
I want to create a shortest-distance line shapefile between points (about 5000 points) and a line shapefile.
The 'shortest line between features' tool serves my purpose except in some places (like 100 places). I have a canal shapefile which I am not allowed to cross. So I need to use the canal trace as a barrier for this operation.
Can anyone share their advice on this?


You should provide sample data or more details about the data structure, e.g.: one or more features on the two line layers? How should the solution look like in case the canal is in between the point and the line? A screenshot would also help

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site. THe most frequent comments here are, "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" Clearly, the Shortest Line tool is the wrong tool when barriers need to be considered. So, what else have you tried?

@Babel I have updated my query with an screenshot.

@Vince, I tried to do that with a query in  'create virtual layer' . I was not succeed as my coding knowledge was poor.

So there should be no connection at all or should the canal be used instead of the intented layer?

@Fjedsen, no I can not connect across canal trace.

Is it acceptable to just remove the forbidden line (easy to do as a second steep) or do you need to find the shortest line that do not cross the canal ?

@J.R if the shortest line crosses the canal line, I need to connect it with the next closest line. I couldn't find a way other than selecting those connections and connecting it manually with the next closest line.

On a side note, the "shortest" lines on the picture are not the shortest, they are not perpendicular to the line layer. Make sure you are using a suitable local projection, so not 4326 nor 3857.

You can achieve this using a virtual layer. The trick is to build the "shortest line" but to exclude such line if they cross a feature from the canal layer.
In the example below I have limited the search to lines within a given distance.

go to the menu Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer... and enter the query. Adjust the layer name and feel free to add/remove any other fields from the point or line layers.
SELECT ST_ShortestLine (pt.geometry, ln.geometry), 
    min(st_distance(pt.geometry, ln.geometry)) dist, 
    pt.id, ln.id
FROM mypointlayer pt
    JOIN mylinelayer ln on ST_DistanceWithin(pt.geometry, ln.geometry,20000)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM mycanallayer canal
    WHERE st_intersects(canal.geometry, ST_ShortestLine (pt.geometry, ln.geometry))
)
group by pt.id
order by st_distance(pt.geometry, ln.geometry) asc

You can refer to this post for an explanation on how the min(dist) + group by + order by dist ensures only the shortest (closest) line is returned, and not one by line feature :)
